# Postgres psql output strings without escape characters

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a column in PostgreSQL that is of type bytea that usually has text data. I want to get the value of that column for a certain row with newlines and tabs intact rather than the octal escape characters that psql is outputting. For example, I run:

```
psql -Atc 'SELECT my_column from my_table limit 1;'
```

And I get output like:

```
Foo\015\012Bar\011This is some text.
```

Instead I want:

```
Foo
Bar This is some text.
```

I realize I can just use grep, which is what I'm doing, but I'm wondering if there's some simple way to do this via psql. I tried type casting the value to type text, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: And if you have text but want bytea, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283973/how-to-display-invisible-unicode-characters-in-psql-postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to convert your bytea in this way to ascii:

```
psql -Atc "SELECT convert_from (my_column, 'SQL_ASCII') from my_table limit 1;"
```

Comment: Clever solution. Note, however, that non-printable characters will create very "creative" outcome this way. [Sqlfiddle to play with ...](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/359)