# How to display "invisible" unicode characters in psql / postgres?

Tags: postgresql, psql

How can I display normally invisible unicode characters from within psql (the postgres command line client)?

Comment: The inverse of this question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249641/postgres-psql-output-strings-without-escape-characters

Answer (score 18):

To see otherwise invisible Unicode in a postgress table, you'll want to use "encode" and "escape" both.  And just for fun, the escape function requires a cast to type bytea.  Putting it all together:

```
# CREATE TABLE xxx_test (foo text);
# INSERT INTO xxx_test (foo) values (E'Invis\u200eble €');

# SELECT foo from xxx_test;
Invis‎ble €
# SELECT encode(foo::bytea, 'escape') FROM xxx_test;
Invis\342\200\216ble \342\202\254

# DROP TABLE xxx_test;
```

Comment: and how to do select *all* with escape?