# UPDATE query produces no change

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, psql

I wrote the following UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE print_archive
SET pages = pages*2
WHERE printer ILIKE '%plot%' AND paper_size = 'Arch D';
```

It will look in a table named print_archive for any printers with "plot" in their name and the paper size 'Arch D'.

If it finds any it is suppose to multiply the page count by 2.

Below is a sample of the print_archive table data -
(column names)
**"name_id","printer","pages","source","date","file_name","duplex","paper_size"**

Sample Data:

```
jane, \\PRINTSRV\plot9, 1, \\COMP-01, 01/21/2017 14:30:39, hello_world.pdf, No, Arch D,

billy, \\PRINTSRV\Plot13, 1, \\COMP-02, 02/20/2016 10:37:23, bye_world.doc, No, Arch D,
```

But no matter what I change or how many times I run the UPDATE statement it always returns 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The two records you included in your question should have been updated.  Is there any chance you have extra whitespace in one/both of the columns?

Comment: Run `select * from print_archive where printer ilike '%plot%' and paper_size = 'Arch D'` - those are the records that will be updated. Do you get 2 rows?

Comment: Would it work if you changed ILIKE to LIKE?

Comment: type of pages column is integer ?

Comment: @latlong if it wasn't numeric and lets say text, then he would get error instead. I would also check if there is trigger on update.

Comment: @giorgiga when I run your query I get no results. very strange. This is a new table I just created from a CSV import. However if I just run a simple select * from print_archive it returns all records (over 300,000). Though I can run a query against the 'name_id', 'pages' but not 'printer' or 'paper_size'. I just get blank results with the latter two. I don't have any index if that matters.

Comment: @giorgiga  I used the following to create the table:CREATE TABLE print_archive
(
name_id character varying(100),
printer character varying(50),
pages integer,
source character varying(60),
date timestamp,
file_name text,
duplex boolean,
paper_size character varying(20)
);

Comment: @giorgiga this is what I used to import the CSV: COPY print_archive(name_id,printer,pages,source,date,file_name,duplex,paper_size,total_jobs)
FROM 'C:\Temp\Print_Archive.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'latin1';

Comment: Dunno, maybe your origin csv contains non-breaking spaces (U+00a0)?

Comment: Yeah, sounds to me like you might have some weird non-printable characters hanging out in your data. Make sure you've got your encoding right (in particular, an ANSI-encoded Windows file is more likely to be `WIN1252` than `LATIN1`). You can try to hunt these characters down with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18283974).

Comment: It looks like there are leading spaces in your CSV, have you tried `... AND paper_size = ' Arch D';` ? ( or : `... AND paper_size ILIKE '%Arch D%'; `)

Answer (score 0):

So initially I had added the latin1 encoding when importing the CSV file as the import process kept producing encoding error messages when using the default encode. I switched the import of the CSV file to '**latin2**' and that worked better. There does seem to be a leading space as well in some of the fields so adding '%' helped as well (though this was not working in latin1). pgAdmin4 (which is how my users will interact) handles latin2 pretty good. Though from psql cmd I need to set the client encoding to latin2 before it can work (SET client_encoding to 'latin2';)

Thanks guys. All your recommendations and leads helped me.